# Mongoose | Object changes in pre-save hook are not saved to db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

I've run into a problem, that I'm not able to solve.
I'll try to describe it as meaningful and simple as possible.
This is my method, that handles post request and saves data:

```
app.post('/users/', (req, res) => {
    let body = _.pick(req.body, ["email", "password"]);
    let user = new User(body);

    user.save().then(
        user => res.json(user),
        err => res.send(err)
    )
});
```

When I save new user to database, this pre-save hook fires:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    if(user.isNew){
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                user.password = hash;
                console.log(user);
                next();
            })
        })
    }
    next();
})
```

For this input in POST body:

```
{
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "password": "somepass"
}
```

console.log from pre-save hook logs:

```
{ __v: 0,
  email: 'example@example.com',
  password: '$2a$10$tWuuvw.wGicr/BTzHaa7k.TdyZRc5ADDV0X1aKnItvVm6JYVe5dsa',
  _id: 59482e8136fd8d2bf41e24b7 
}
```

however in db I've got:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59482e8136fd8d2bf41e24b7"),
    "email" : "example@example.com",
    "password" : "somepass",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Clearly changes on user object are not saved and in save() method I still use old values with unhashed password. Why is that? And how can I make changes from pre-save hook to be stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're always calling `next()` after the `if` block, even when the password needs async encrypting.

Change your code to only do that for existing `user` docs:

```
if(user.isNew){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            user.password = hash;
            console.log(user);
            next();
        })
    })
}
else {
    next();
}
```

Comment: I simply cannot believe I didn't figure it on my own. That's awfully silly. Thank you very much, JohnnyHK! Best regards!

Comment: For anyone in the future, if you are using mongoose pre save, dont use async, this answer tipped me off.